# Inventory turns formula doesn't seem to give intuitive results

Tags: accounting

In this image, I purchase $100 worth of inventory, sell all of it, purchase another $100 worth, and sell all of that (in some time period).  This looks like it should equal 2 turns:

[image: Graph of (ostensibly) two turns of inventory]

However, using the formula:

```
Turns = COGS / Avg Inventory
```

I insert the following:

- COGS = $200 = 2 x $100.
- Avg Inventory = $50, which is (beginning inventory + ending inventory) / 2 = (100 + 0) / 2. But 200 / 50 is **4**, not 2.

Does this actually reflect 2 turns, as it appears to on the surface?  Or am I plugging in a wrong number?  COGS can't be $100 because I've spent $200 on goods to sell over the time period.  Average inventory can't be $100 because I only have $100 on the shelf for two instants during the time period; I have an average of $50 over the time period.  If 2 is not the correct answer, why not?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Inventory turnover is a measure of "how many times did I sell my average inventory in a year". It's not "how many times did I deplete my inventory". In reality, inventory is generally more stable since you replace inventory as it is sold. So it can still be a "sawtooth" but it's a swatooth that's always > 0:

[image]

In your case, your average inventory over the period is 50 (though your formula is not correct in general - the formula would be the total inventory on each day divided by the number of days). Since you sold 200, you sold your "average" inventory amount 4 times in that period.

Comment: This is how statistics "lie" to us, why it's so important to understand statistics, and why "common sense intuition" is so often wrong.

Comment: "How many times did I sell my average" versus "How many times did I deplete" was the key!  Thank you very much.  (I apparently do not have enough points to upvote your ansewr, but would have if I could have.)

Comment: @user3511585 No worries - glad it helped!